# How Split H2 database into multiple files according to tables

Tags: java, database, h2

I would like to split H2 databases into multiple files and each file will represent one table.
For example: let's say we have t1 and t2 tables, right no I have only one file myDB.mv.db but the required output should be t1.mv.db and t1.mv.db

I know that I can handle it by creating connections (DB) to each table. but I want to have only one java process.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened connections to multiple H2 databases on the same Java program using different URLs. For example you can connect to the following databases:

```
jdbc:h2:file:mydatabase1

jdbc:h2:file:mydatabase2
```

Tables on each one of those will be stored in separate folders. You can have multiple tables on each one.

In your case, if you have 5 tables, you could create 5 connections and create each table on each one.